# PBS with bash positional parameter

Tags: bash, pbs

I know the -N can set the corresponding job name such as

```
#PBS -N JobName
```

Is that possible to use positional parameter such as $1
It is like

```
#PBS -N $1
```

Therefore, I can use positional parameter $1
Then I can use

```
qsub mybash.sh $1
```

I would be grateful if someone has any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this, in a script?  If so, sure, you should be fine using a variable, though you'll almost certainly want to put it in double quotes: `PBS -n "$1"` to prevent word splitting and globbing from happening to the value in `$1`

Comment: @EricRenouf I should explain it clearer. I'm looking for a way to submit my PBS bash such as `qsub mybash.sh $1`

Comment: Why would that be more useful than simply invoking the script as `qsub -N "$1" mybash.sh`?

Comment: @chepner Actually, you pointed out the problem. I should use the other way around, and that works as what I wanted. Thanks.